# How correctly to parse text from div block?

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

I am working with my own Android application and I am new in parsing. I have website where I have such block of code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em">
    some text <br> some text <br> some text
</div> </div>
```

I want take this text and give it to the TextView on the screen. So I wrote this code for AsyncTask, but it doesn't work.

```
class NewPostsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private String title; // Тут храним значение заголовка сайта
    private String pst;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Новые");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Document doc = null; // Здесь хранится будет разобранный html документ
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get(); // Считываем заголовок страницы

            // Using Elements to get the Meta data
            Elements post = doc.select("div[class=col-xs-12]");
            // Locate the content attribute
            pst = post.attr("[style=margin:0.5em 0;line-height:1.785em]");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // Если не получилось считать
        }

        // Если всё считалось, то вытаскиваем из считанного html документа заголовок
        if (doc != null)
            title = doc.title();
        else
            title = "Ошибка";

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        //websitePost.setText(title);
        websitePost.setText(pst);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Can you explain me how I should do this and can you show me my mistakes?

P. S. Sorry if my English is not good.

Comment: you should add the exception or output or something

Comment: @DreadfulWeather I don't have exception, because it works fine, but I haven't output on the TextView.

Comment: can you select the element you want using that selector if so check the string using text() method on your element

Comment: IIRC ~ your content element should be `post.text()` not the css attr query you're using.

Comment: @EddieB oh, thanks! You helped me! Please write this to the answer and I will choose your answer like a solution :)

Comment: Thanks Kostya ~ updated an answer :)

Comment: @EddieB do you know how correctly to parse many same div blocks? It is something like Twitter, on website I have many similar posts. Now, I got all these posts on one TextView. I want make this with ArrayList and it must look like Twitter. Have any suggestion about logic of this solution?

Comment: Please create a new question for this. However, you'll need to store the results in a Collection of some type... `Set,Map,List` For the record, you can push the results of your `AsyncTask` into a collection for you. I.E. `AsyncTask<Map, Void, Void>` etc.

Comment: @EddieB thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC you are not referencing the proper element for your use case. You should be referencing `post.text()`

```
...
// Using Elements to get the Meta data
Elements post = doc.select("div[class=col-xs-12]");
// Locate the content attribute
pst = post.text();
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) instead of doing all that parsing ?

```
aTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourHtmlString));
```